# Cannot use component from other module in MatDialog

Tags: angular

I have two modules, AModule and BModule.

AModule declares and exports a component, called ProductCardComponent, which has one input, which is

```
@Input() product: ProductModel
```

Now in BModule I import AModule and I'm opening a MatDialog which tries to render the product card as such:

```
<app-product-card [product]="product">
```

However, I get the error `Can't bind to 'product' since it isn't a known property of 'app-product-card'.` If I remove the binding, the component doesn't render at all, which gives me the impression that it simply cannot find the component. I can use it in other places alright.

What am I missing here?

UPDATE: as I was fiddling around I realised other things like `*ngFor` and `async` also didn't work, as if the component wasn't in any module declaration, but still functioned. I then realised the module was lazy loaded. I added BModule to the imports of my main AppModule, and behold, it all started functioning!

Comment: can you create a stackblitz example for that.

Comment: Did you add the dialog component to `entryComponents` in BModule?

Comment: @KamilAugustyniak I'm running Angular 9, so that's no longer necessary

Comment: Can you share the import array in BModule?

Answer (score 2):

As i see you are using different Modules A and B. Which will not work in thise case, You should create a shared module with the components you want to use, export these components, and import the shared module in your other modules

Comment: I forgot to mention that BModule imports AModule (I've updated the original post), so I would expect the exported component to be available in BModule